# Is it illegal to refuse to fix a hacked website?

Tags: internet, gdpr, hacking, security

Suppose there's a website or a server that has been hacked. There is no personal data stored anywhere, so there hasn't been a real data breach, because basically there's no valuable data to steal at all. A typical example could be a simple website that only contains public info about a company, or maybe a personal blog where all the posts are public anyway.

Now suppose the owner of that website or server refuses to fix it, because they don't have the ability, the time, or most often the money to fix it. The question is: is it legal to leave your website or server compromised, for an indefinite time? Technically it should be a problem, because even if there hasn't been a data breach and the owner isn't suffering any losses, their server or application might be used to commit other crimes (launch other attacks, host illegal stuff without the owner's consent, etc.). However I'm not sure if it's illegal to just keep a server compromised, unless the owner has been notified that their server is the source of some other attack (then I believe they should at least put if offline).

Jurisdictions I'm interested in: Europe and United States.

Comment: what kind of compromised is it? is the site malicious now or is the info just wrong?

Comment: @Trish, my question is pretty generic, if it is important to make a distinction between different kinds of infection then I guess that argument could be included in the answers. I don't even know if it matters whether the owner is aware of the infection or not.

Comment: It makes a HELL lot of difference if the webpage is just illegally used to store something or if the website propagates virii or used in a DDOS or if someone just turned the site into a hell lot of misinformation